# How to hide searchBar under navigation bar and show it when user pull the tableView down?

Tags: ios, swift3, uisearchbar

in my app I want to implement searchBar above the tableView which will hide under navigationBar. when user pull the tableView down then I want to show the searchBar. Please tell me how I can achieve this in swift. Thanks!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aee0S.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set up rootViewController with UINavigationController in AppDelegate.swift.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())

        return true
    }
```

Then in ViewController.swift, add TableView by properly implementing  UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods. 
Then, declare  UISearchController and add it to tableHeaderView instead of adding as subview. Then, set the content offset of tableView so that by default the searchController is hidden. When tableView is scrolled down, then only searchBar is shown.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    private var myData: NSArray = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

    private var tableView: UITableView!

    //lazy var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        navigationItem.title = "Home"

        tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        self.tableView.backgroundColor = .brown

        let searchBarController: UISearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBarController.searchBar

        tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 44), animated: false)

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("\(indexPath.row)")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = myData[indexPath.row] as! String
        cell.backgroundColor = .brown
        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Initially when the application is first launched searchBar is hidden, only tableView is displayed:
[image]

After tableView is scrolled down, then searchBar appears:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @bthapa !! I am able to implement the same, can you please explain how can I push the search bar over navigation bar with cancel button on it when tapped on search bar textfield

Comment: For this to achieve, you need to add two UISearchBarDelegate methods which are searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) and searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar). 
When the searchBar is tapped, hide the navigationBar by using setNavigationBarHidden() which already defined in UINavigationBarController.
Here is the link of complete source code of how I did it simply.

    https://github.com/bthapa4791/TableViewWithSearchBarController

Comment: Thank you so much @bthapa . I followed the approach but when I am clicking on the searchBarSearchButtonClicked the navigation is hiding but the searchBar is not showing up on the navigationBar. when clicked on searchBarSearchButtonClicked I'm doing navigationBarHidden = true, please see attached screenshot. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Simply make the table view or collection view scroll to the first row right after setting the search controller.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  
  navigationItem.searchController = searchController
  
  tableView.scrollToRow(
    at: .init(row: 0, section: 0),
    at: [.bottom, .left],
    animated: false
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could hide the searchBar with this code

```
 let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.searchbar()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    //Hide SearchBar
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 44), animated: false)
  }

func searchbar() {
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self as UISearchResultsUpdating
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To initially hide the `searchBar`, simply set the `navigationItem.searchController` property ***after*** your table view (or collection view) has been populated with data.